# How to get the class of a static object attribute

Tags: java, object, abstract

I have a parent class Tile and inherited classes Walltile, FloorTile, EntityTile. Each inherited class have BufferedImage attributes that is related with its name.

```
public class WallTile extends Tile {

public static BufferedImage WATER_TOP_LEFT = Game.tilesSpritesheet.getSprite(34, 0);
public static BufferedImage WATER_TOP = Game.tilesSpritesheet.getSprite(51, 0);
public static BufferedImage WATER_TOP_RIGHT = Game.tilesSpritesheet.getSprite(68, 0);
public static BufferedImage WATER_LEFT = Game.tilesSpritesheet.getSprite(34, 17);
public static BufferedImage WATER_CENTER = Game.tilesSpritesheet.getSprite(51, 17);
public static BufferedImage WATER_RIGHT = Game.tilesSpritesheet.getSprite(68, 17);
public static BufferedImage WATER_BOTTOM_LEFT = Game.tilesSpritesheet.getSprite(34, 34);
public static BufferedImage WATER_BOTTOM = Game.tilesSpritesheet.getSprite(51, 34);
public static BufferedImage WATER_BOTTOM_RIGHT = Game.tilesSpritesheet.getSprite(68, 34);
public static BufferedImage WATER_LITTLE_TOP_LEFT = Game.tilesSpritesheet.getSprite(17, 34);

public WallTile(BufferedImage sprite, int x, int y) {
    super(sprite, x, y);
}
}

public class FloorTile extends Tile {

public static BufferedImage TILE_GRASS = Game.tilesSpritesheet.getSprite(85, 0);
public static BufferedImage TILE_SAND = Game.tilesSpritesheet.getSprite(136, 0);

public FloorTile(BufferedImage sprite, int x, int y) {
    super(sprite, x, y);
}
}

public class EntityTile extends Tile {

public static BufferedImage TILE_TREE_1 = Game.tilesSpritesheet.getSprite(221, 153);
public static BufferedImage TILE_TALL_GRASS = Game.tilesSpritesheet.getSprite(374, 187);

public static List<BufferedImage> spriteList = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();

// Construtor
public EntityTile(BufferedImage sprite, int x, int y) {
    super(sprite, x, y);
}

@Override
public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(FloorTile.TILE_GRASS, x - Camera.x, y - Camera.y, null);
    g.drawImage(sprite, x - Camera.x, y - Camera.y, null);
}
}
```

I instantiate Tile and then i cast to the specific class, like:

```
Tile tile = new Tile(sprite, 0, 0);
WallTile wt = (WallTile) tile;
```

But i need to know if this Tile object is WallTile, FloorTile or EntityTile. For that i have the sprite attribute which corresponds to the ****Tile class i want. How can i get this info? When i use sprite.getClass() it returns BufferedImage, but i need return like WallTile, FloorTile or EntityTile.
To do this:

```
if (tile.sprite.getClass().toString() == "class World.WallTile")
    //do something
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of your code does **not** create a `WallTile` object.

```java
Tile tile = new Tile(sprite, 0, 0);
```

The above line creates a `Tile` object and hence cannot be cast to `WallTile`.

I couldn't find the code for class `Tile` in your question but I guess that you should make it an abstract class and give the constructor `protected` access so as to avoid directly constructing `Tile` objects.

Consider class `Furniture` and its subclass `Table`. I can create a `Table` but I can't create a `Furniture` because `Furniture` is a general term. Its purpose is to store common attributes from all types of furniture.

Similarly, your `Tile` class is a base class that simply stores attributes that are common to `WallTile`, `FloorTile` and `EntityTile`.

The following line of code will create a `WallTile` as a `Tile` object and hence can be cast.

```java
Tile tile = new WallTile(sprite, 0, 0); // 'tile' is actually 'WallTile' instance
WallTile wallTile = (WallTile) tile;
```

The `sprite` attribute of class `Tile` is a `BufferedImage`, regardless of the type of object that it is an attribute of. So the *class* of `sprite` will **always** be `BufferedImage`. What you can do is check what `sprite` it actually is, since all possible values for `sprite` must be one of the constants that you defined.

So in order to determine whether a `Tile` object is actually a `WallTile`, for example, you could do something like the following:

```java
if (sprite == WallTile.WATER_TOP_LEFT ||
    sprite == WallTile.WATER_TOP      ||
    // etc) {
}
```

Still, I'm wondering why you need to do this. You didn't post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so the context is missing. I don't know how you obtain a `Tile` object and why you need to determine the actual type of `Tile` it is. Nonetheless, can you not simply do the following?

```java
if (tile instanceof WallTile)
```